# How to detect abnormal fetal head size with image classification?

Tags: deep-learning, image-classification, convolutional-neural-network, pytorch

I'm writing Python code to predict fetal head circumference 10mm range using classification.
The model will train to classify a fetal head image into a range (e.g., 50–60 mm) representing its circumference.

But for some reason, the loss always stays at 3.5 and I'm not sure what approach might help get better results.

[Link to notebook](https://www.kaggle.com/code/nitayl/fetalhcclassification)

Comment: Is there a reason you don’t want to predict the head size itself?